# Delete consecutive duplicates: "File sharing lock count exceeded" at 9k of 1m records

Tags: vba, database, ms-access, duplicates, file-locking

I need to **remove consecutive duplicate** records from a large table (It could contain 200k-1 million records, and about **half the records will be deleted**).

`DateTime` is unique. Records where the remaining fields match the previous record, should be deleted, leaving the "first" record. (Non-consecutive duplicates should stay.)

```
       DateTime        Field1   Field2   Field3  
 -------------------- -------- -------- -------- 
  2018-09-01 5:20:33      123      456      789  
  2018-09-01 5:20:34      123      456      789        ← delete
  2018-09-01 5:20:35      123      654      987  
  2018-09-01 5:20:36      234      567      890  
  2018-09-01 5:20:37      234      567      890        ← delete 
  2018-09-01 5:20:38      234      567      890        ← delete 
  2018-09-01 5:20:39      123      456      789
```

I'm iterating through the recordset (ordered by date) to delete duplicates, but when I hit about 9,500 deletions I get:

> ```
> Error 3052: File sharing lock count exceeded.  
>             Increase MaxLocksPerFile registry entry.
> ```

As per [these instructions](https://support.microsoft.com/en-ca/help/815281/file-sharing-lock-count-exceeded-error-message-during-large-transactio), I could increase the value in the registry, or with the `SetOption` method, however **I'm not clear on the impact** of doing so since it appears I'd need to increase the value from `9,500` to at least `500,000` or more...  I'm not sure, but this seems like a bad idea.

---

**Simplified version of my code:**

```
Sub example_DelDupes()
    Dim rs As Recordset, delCount As Long, rCount as long
    Dim thisRecord As String, prevRecord As String
    Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("select * from myTable order by DateTime")
    With rs
        .MoveLast            'so I can get a recordcount...
        .MoveFirst
        rCount = .RecordCount '...required for progress bar (not shown)

        Do While Not .EOF
            thisRecord = !field1$ & !field2$ & !field3$ 'actually 
            If thisRecord = prevRecord Then
                .Delete                      'delete this record
                delCount = delCount + 1
            Else
                prevRecord = thisRecord
            End If
            .MoveNext
        Loop

        .Close
    End With
    Set rs = Nothing
End Sub
```

I thought that deleting from the set I'm iterating could be the issue, so instead of `.Delete` I also tried *marking* the records to be deleted, with the intention of deleting them after the loop completes, but editing produced the same error as deleting.

---

I suspect there may be a better way to accomplish my task, perhaps by opening the recordset with a [different `LockTypeEnum`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/office/ff834802.aspx), or by approaching this a different way altogether, but I'm hoping to avoid trial-and-error.

Thoughts?   Thanks!   <sub>[image: img]</sub>

Comment: Did you end up solving this problem? I am dealing with something similar.

Answer (score 3):

I'd delete everything in a single query instead of iterating over the recordset.

You can use a nested subquery to test if the row before satisfies your condition:

```
DELETE o.*
FROM MyTable o
WHERE EXISTS(
    SELECT 1 
    FROM MyTable i 
    WHERE o.Field1 = i.Field1 And o.Field2 = i.Field2 AND o.Field3 = i.Field3 
    AND EXISTS (
        SELECT  1
        FROM MyTable i2 
        WHERE i2.DateTime < o.DateTime
        HAVING Max(i2.DateTime) = i.DateTime
    )
)
```

Comment: Great answer, thanks.  Unfortunately the sheer size of my dataset seems to be a problem .  However, this works great on more reasonably-sized sets.